# Can I send an alert from the server to the client in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, client, server, alert

is there a way I can sent an alert from the server to the client? For example, a user clicks a button. That button calls a method on the server that checks if the user has been assigned an ID# yet. If the user has not been assigned an ID#, I want the browser to get an alert. I could easily do a check if I publish the ID# to the client, but the ID# is very sensitive and so I don't want to publish it. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http call to server, evaluate response and alert if needed. where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

1) On the client, create a button click listener that runs a Meteor method.

```
// CLIENT
Template.example.events({
    'click button': function () {
        Meteor.call('checkIfUserHasId', function (err, userHasId) {
            if (!userHasId) {
                alert('user has no id');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

2) On the server, create the Meteor method that checks if the user has an id.

```
// SERVER
Meteor.methods({
    checkIfUserHasId: function () {
        // check if user has id
        return true; // or false depending whether user has id or not
    }
});
```

Meteor methods can be called remotely on the client but are defined on the server. This should help achieve what you want in terms of not exposing the id's when performing the check.